# JQuery - upload and show preview image (based on ZURB)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm newbie in scripting and try to follow Zurb articles on [Image Uploads with 100% Less Suck. Guaranteed](http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload). But still can not make it right. On requirement said that I need JQuery and AjaxUpload plugin. So I do make links to files needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.zurb.com/javascripts/plugins/ajaxupload.js"></script>
```

(Sorry Zurb and others that I use the links, I use the file for educational purpose only. I don't mean anything bad)

This is the script that I follow from Zurb

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var thumb = $('img#thumb'); 

    new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
        action: $('form#testForm').attr('action'),
        name: 'image',
        onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
            $('div.preview').addClass('loading');
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            thumb.load(function(){
                $('div.preview').removeClass('loading');
                thumb.unbind();
            });
            thumb.attr('src', response);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
span.wrap { padding: 10px; }
        span.wrap.new { margin-left: 30px; }        
        span.wrap button { display: block; margin-top: 10px; }
        span.wrap label { margin-bottom: 5px; }
        div.preview { float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px dotted #CCCCCC; }
        div.preview.loading { background: url(http://www.woningcorporatie-processen.nl/static/modules/sensus/images/loading.gif) no-repeat 39px 40px; }
        div.preview.loading img {display: none; }
        input#imageUpload { width: 400px; }     
        span.wrap form { margin: 0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="preview">
        <img id="thumb" width="100px" height="100px" src="https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/blankLogo.gif" />
    </div>

    <span class="wrap new">
        <form id="testForm" action="ajax_upload">
            <label>Upload a Picture of Yourself</label>
            <input type="file" id="imageUpload" size="20" />
        <button type="submit" class="button">Save</button>
        </form>
    </span>
</div>
```

Already try in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEQVM/) but not working good. Can you guys help what I supposed to do so I can preview the uploaded image with this Jquery?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably a silly question, but do you have an "ajax_upload" file on the server to receive the file? It's not immediately obvious from the zurb article, but you need some server side code to save the image somewhere, make the thumbnail and send back the address of the thumbnail.

Comment: Oh my, you right Dan F. I don't have the "ajax_upload" to receive the file. In fact I don't know how to make the 'ajax_upload' but I'll learn how to make and try it. Forgive my further ignorance question, but do you know perhaps where I can start to learn it? Thank you.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. It all depends what your serverside language is. Luckily, it's pretty easy to find examples out there for pretty much every language on the planet. Good luck!